# Cannot Display Sprites in Autodesk Data Visualization Extension Demo

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-data-visualization

I replicated the [APS DataViz Extensions Demo](https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-iot-extensions-demo) and I have used my own **Model URN**.

For the **Model GUID**, I left it an empty string. All other extensions (Sensor List, Sensor Detail, and Sensor Heatmap) works.

I have adjusted my iot.mocked.js code to suits the `ObjectID` and coordinate of the objects where I want the sensors to be attached.
Despite all these efforts, the Sensors Logo or Sprites do not appear on the viewer.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question, but have you restarted the node.js server after changing the contents of `iot.mocked.js`?